# Heroku Django postgres migration merge: psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation already exists

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, database-migration, django-migrations

This is a Heroku-specific issue with a Django project 1.11.24 running Python 3.6.5 and a Heroku postgres database.

During testing of two different branches during development, different conflicting migration files were deployed at different times to the Heroku server. We recognized this, and have now merged the migrations, but the order the Heroku psql db schema was migrated is out of order with the current migration files.

As a result, specific tables already exist, so on deploy applying the updated merged migration files errs with:

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "table_foo" already exists
```

In `heroku run python manage.py showmigrations -a appname` all of the migrations are shown as having run.

We've followed Heroku's docs and done the following:

- Rolled back the app itself to before when the conflicting migrations took place and were run (https://blog.heroku.com/releases-and-rollbacks)
- Rolled back the postgres db itself to a datetime before when the conflicting migrations took place and were run (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-rollback)

However, despite both app and db rollbacks, when we check the db tables themselves in the rollback in pql shell with `\dt`, the table causing the DuplicateTable err still exists, so the db rollback doesn't actually seem to effect the `django_migrations` table.

It's Heroku, so we can't fake the migrations.

We could attempt to drop the specific db tables that already exist (or drop the entire db, since it's a test server), but that seems like bad practice. Is there any other way to address this in Heroku? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this by manually modifying migration files to align with the schema dependency order that was established. Very unsatisfying fix, wish Heroku offered a better solution for this (or a longer postgres database rollback window)